# Elementor Combined all Sections into 1 Text Editor

Tags: plugins, pages, block-editor, frontpage

I am hoping someone might be able to help me with this.

I used Elementor to edit my front page, which was great because it was nicely organized with sections and content and everything.

Now I just went back to my page and clicked on edit with Elementor and all my sections are now combined into one big text editor which is inside the top-level section. Due to this the structure and content is not easily updated with Elementor.

Does anyone know what happened and if there is a possibility of getting my Elementor sections back?

Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, questions regarding third-party products are off-topic here, and it's not likely that this question can be answered without a fair bit of knowledge regarding Elementor and it's inner workings. You should enquire in Elementor's support channels or more general communities!

Comment: @bosco Thanks will do!

Comment: @danielmeegan did you find the solution?